# Mavericks Finder Sidebar Bug?

Tags: macos, finder, bug, eject

I think I noticed this in progress indicator getting misplaced from next to my Time Machine when I ejected a USB stick, but is that some sort of oddly placed AirDrop indicator? (the arrows are spinning)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It's most likely AirDrop sync'ing.